# EntityManager.merge() is not being committed (Wildfly, JPA, JTA)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jta

I can persist new data, but I cannot do updates. There are no errors, just no transactions committing the changes. I'm assuming this has something to do with the way that I've set up transactions. I'm trying a bunch of relatively new (to me) set of technologies. Below are the details.

I'm using the following tools/technologies:

- Wildfly 8 and Java 7 (which is what my hosting service uses)
- Annotations, with minimal XML being the goal
- Struts 2.3 (using the convention plugin)
- Spring 3.2
- Hibernate 4.3
- JTA (with container managed transactions (CMT))
- JPA 2 (with a Container Managed Persistence Context)
- EJBs (I have a remote client app that runs htmlunit tests)
- Three WAR files and one EJB JAR file deployed
- SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor to autowire the EJBs (could there be an error in here where transactions don't commit?)

beanRefContext.xml (required by SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor)

```
<beans>
  <bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:campaignerContext.xml" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

campaignerContext.xml

```
<beans> 
  <context:component-scan base-package="..." />   
  <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/CampaignerDS"/>
  <tx:annotation-driven/> 
  <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>  
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="campaigner" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="ehCacheManager" class="net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager" factory-method="create">
    <constructor-arg type="java.net.URL" value="classpath:/campaigner_ehcache.xml"/>
  </bean> 
</beans>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence>
  <persistence-unit name="campaigner" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/CampaignerDS</jta-data-source>

    <class>....UserRegistration</class>
    ...

    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"  value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
     </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

SecurityServiceBean.java

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
@DeclareRoles("Security Admin")
public class SecurityServiceBean extends AbstractCampaignerServiceImpl implements
    SecurityServiceLocal, SecurityServiceRemote
{
  @Override
  @PermitAll
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public UserRegistration confirmRegistration(
    String confirmationCode) throws ApplicationException
  {
      UserRegistration userRegistration = this.userRegistrationDAO
      .find(new UserRegistrationQuery(null, confirmationCode)).uniqueResult(); // Should be attached now

    ...
          userRegistration.setConfirmationDate(new Date());
          userRegistration.setState(State.CONFIRMED);
          userRegistration = this.userRegistrationDAO.saveOrUpdate(userRegistration);
    ...
  }
}
```

UserRegistrationDAO.java

```
@Override
public UserRegistration saveOrUpdate(
  UserRegistration obj) throws DAOException
{
  log.debug("[saveOrUpdate] isJoinedToTransaction? "
            + (this.em.isJoinedToTransaction() ? "Y " : "N"));

  try
  {
    if (obj.getId() == null)
    {
      this.em.persist(obj);

      log.debug("[saveOrUpdate] called persist()");

      return obj;
    }
    else
    {
      UserRegistration attached = this.em.merge(obj);

      log.debug("[saveOrUpdate] called merge()");

      return attached;
    }
  }
  catch (PersistenceException e)
  {
    throw new DAOException("[saveOrUpdate] obj=" + obj.toString() + ",msg=" + e.getMessage(), e);
  }
}
```

Are there any settings in Wildfly's standalone.xml that you need to see or that I should be setting?

BTW, this is incredibly annoying and frustrating. This should be an easy one-time setup that I can do and then forget about as I move on to creating my website, which should be where most of my time is spent. The lack of comprehensive documentation anywhere is AMAZING. Right now, development has been halted until this is solved
/rant

UPDATES

- I tried switching to an XA data source, because some sites claimed that was necessary, but that didn't work (didn't think so but had to try). Also tried configuring emf with dataSource instead of persistenceUnitName as some other sites have. No joy.
- I tried replacing the transactionManager with JpaTransactionManager, but that just led to this exception: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Comment: `@EnableTransactionManagement` is pretty much useless here, it only works on `@Configuration` annotated classes (and you already have `<tx:annotation-driven />`. As you are using EJBs you should also take care that you are using the proper `@Transactional` annotation else the container will not start a transaction, nor will spring as the EJB isn't spring managed.

Comment: Thanks for the information. When you say "proper @Transactional annotation", what do you mean? Are you talking about the propagation attribute?

Comment: No that you are using the correct one, you shouldn't be using the spring version but the EJB version.

Comment: Wow! That was it. Thanks so much!

Comment: the thing i don't understand is why do you need spring transactions when you are already using EJBs which came with default transaction support ? I could understand the usage of spring transactions without EJBs but if you are not using EJBs tx management capabilities why do you using EJB? Is there anyone out there knows what what he is doing?

Comment: You may have a point. This version of Spring is new to me and I've just been grabbing from sites that show how to use Struts2 (I've been using Struts1) plus use annotations to inject beans (including EJBs) plus how to use JPA (also new to me, I've been using xdoclet). I guess most of those sites included the use of Spring transactions. What would I remove to use only EJB transaction management and how would I configure it? Do you have a website to recommend?

Answer (score 0):

The answer, thanks to M. Deinum, is that I was using the wrong @Transactional. I should have been using javax.transaction.Transactional but was using the Spring one instead. Note that the correct one will look like "@Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)" instead of "@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)"